# HAProxy reverse proxy config

Tags: haproxy

I want to migrate some websites to a new server. It takes a couple of days to get all the DNS changes done, so I wanted to set up a HAProxy reverse proxy to redirect all traffic from the old location to the new location. I'm not very experienced with such a config. When visiting a domain, I get an error saying:

`503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request.`

This is the config I used (with hidden IP address):

```
global

  log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot  /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group   haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend localhost
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/haproxy.pem
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   mode http
   default_backend node

backend node
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server dcnode1 x.x.x.x:80 check
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

Comment: I got the exact same error when I visited that hidden IP address.  It looks like whatever is listening on port 80 of that system, can't reach its backend servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the backend is not considered 'up'.

First make sure that the backend server is running and accessible from the HAProxy machine, e.g. `telnet x.x.x.x 80` and make sure it connects.

If you can successfully make a connection, the second thing to check is whether the backend is failing a check.  Try removing `option httpchk`, and remove `check` from the `server` line.  (When you've only got one backend server, a check isn't of huge value, but you can always add it back later)

It may be that your `Host: localhost` is returning something unusual in the check.